# What directory should you put sample config files in?

Tags: linux, software-installation

I'm developing an application that requires a config file in the user's config directory, but I want to avoid placing it there for them when they run `make install`. I've seen other applications ask the user to copy a sample config file to their home directory, and I'm wondering if there's a best practice, system location for these sample config files? Probably something under `/usr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible location is as part of the project’s documentation, perhaps in a dedicated “examples” sub-directory. With `make install` you’d install it in `share/doc/${yourproject}/examples` under the prefix, so `/usr/local/share/doc/${yourproject}/examples` by default.

This is commonly used at least in Debian and RHEL (run `ls -d /usr/share/doc/*/examples` on a Debian or RHEL system).

Comment: I'd recommend this, too. However, note that the string you should use is the package name, not the project name (in case these are different). For example, in case of package `sudo` the example configuration files can be found in `/usr/share/doc/sudo/examples/*.conf`. And the Debian/Ubuntu way to store the changelog is to put it in `/usr/share/doc/sudo/changelog.Debian.gz` which could also mention newly added example config files.

Comment: @Mikko that’s correct in a packaging context, but the question cares about `make install`, which shouldn’t care about a potential package. And for a Debian package you’d typically rely on `dh_installexamples` anyway, which will do the right thing for you.

Comment: I think similar works for make install, too, but you should use prefix /usr/local or /opt to avoid possible collision in namespace with package manager.

Comment: @Mikko yes, but my point is that in a `make install` context, the only meaningful name is the project name — there is no package name (yet). Thus `/usr/local/share/doc/${yourproject}/examples` as indicated in the answer.